# how can you move a shape in a gliffy diagram using the keyboard arrow keys?

Tags: keyboard, gliffy

my company just upgraded to Gliffy 9.3 and I can no longer move a shape with my keyboard arrow keys...bug?

Comment: i just discovered that the arrow keys work, right after i copy&paste a shape. at least that is part of it

Comment: i just discovered that the arrow keys work, when i select all shapes. at least that is part of it

Comment: i think the arrows can no longer be used because of new functionality : when you click on a shape, gliffy shows arrow images in all 4 directions, with which you can quickly create a subsequent shape